# Proving there is a unique associate in the Gaussian integers with both real and imaginary parts nonnegative

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, solution-verification

I wish to prove that for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ there is a unique associate $\beta$ such that $Re(\beta)>0, Im(\beta)\ge 0$. My attempt is as follows:

Suppose there are two associates of $\alpha$, namely $\beta_1,\beta_2$. Then there are units $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2$ such that $\alpha=\beta_1\varepsilon_1=\beta_2\varepsilon_2$. Dividing through we get $\frac{\beta_1}{\beta_2}=\frac{\varepsilon_1}{\varepsilon_2}$. But $|\frac{\varepsilon_1}{\varepsilon_2}|=1$ and so $\beta_1=\pm\beta_2$. Now, if $Re(\beta_1)>0, Im(\beta_1)\ge 0$ then the result follows, but if one is positive and the other is negative the result does not follow. How would I go about proving this?

Comment: I think you are missing some of the units in $\mathbb Z[i]$.  It is not true that $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ must be $\pm 1$.

Comment: @RaviFernandoreally no but their modulus is always $1$ so dividing through gives a modulus of $1$ again

Comment: It's true that $|\varepsilon_1/\varepsilon_2| = 1$.  It's not true that $\beta_1 = \pm \beta_2$.